# Defining extern variables in functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, extern, lnk2001

So I'm learning OpenGL on learnopengl.com. To make my code as clear as possible i decided to split it up into different files and connect them with a header file. I declared an extern variable shaderProgram in a header file and defined it in a setupShaders() function. However when I run the code (I'm using Visual Studio 2019) I get an error, that this variable is not defined. The weird thing is that I use this variable in this same function, just after defining and it still doesn't work.

```
//header.h
extern unsigned int shaderProgram;

//shader.cpp
void setupShaders(){
   shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
   glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader); // error
}
```

Obviously, that's a big simplification of the code

Comment: You cannot define global variables in a function. Its declared at global scope, it must be defined at global scope.

Comment: Thanks, but when i try to define it at a global scope, i get an unhadled exeption "acces violation executing location"

Comment: Your global variable `unsigned int shaderProgram` has not been defined anywhere.  The error you are getting is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have shown is not *defining* the variable at all.  You have *declared* it as `extern`, and you are *assigning* a value it inside your `setupShaders()` function, but you are not actually *defining* any storage for the variable.  You need to add that to your `.cpp` file, eg:

header.h

```cpp
extern unsigned int shaderProgram;
```

shader.cpp

```cpp
unsigned int shaderProgram; // <-- HERE

void setupShaders(){
   shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
   glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
}
```